How to use SerialPort with Electron and Vite
I could use some help getting SserialPort to run with Electron and Vite after I spent my whole day already trying to somehow get my desktop app to talk to my Arduino Uno.
I found some Repositories online (like this one) and tried to copy their approach but I didn't get it to work. Neither in the main, nor in the renderer process.
When running it in the main process, I get
Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=electron abi=130 uv=1 libc=glibc node=20.18.0 electron=33.0.0

Already tried downgrading all the versions to match the ones from SerialPort's example, which works when I clone it but won't work for my project.
When using it in the renderer process, I either get
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

or when marking serialport as external using vite-plugin-externals, I don't get an error but serialport just exports undefined.
Can someonehelp me get this running?
